# Get a Block of Text

Tags: c#, regex

I have a block of text that I need to extract.  I currently use this regex however it is grabbing all text to the end of the file.    How can I adjust the regex to stop once it reaches the first 4 line feeds \r

regex

```
Regex(@"Education(\W+|\D+|\S+)*(^\r\r\r\r)*?", 
  RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);


EDUCATION

    Some Text 
    01/07/1911-             Some Text
    01/23/1988              Some Text

    Some Text               Some Text
    01/11/1999-             Some Text
    01/13/1911              Some Text

    Some Text:              Some Text
    01/01/1966-             Some Text 
    01/30/1911              Some Text   

    Some Text:              Some Text/Some Text
    01/01/1911-             Some Text
    01/30/1911              Some Text
    01/01/1922-             Some Text 
    01/30/1933              Some Text 

Start of other text
```

Comment: Try `@"Education(?:(?!\r{4}).)*"`. You may also want to split with `"\r\r\r\r"`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  Thank you.  If you put that as an answer I will mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you can just use a `String.Split` with `"\r\r\r\r"`.

If you need to use a regex, use

```
@"Education(?:(?!\r{4}).)*"
```

With the `RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` flags (no need to use the multiline one).

The `(?:(?!\r{4}).)*` is a tempered greedy token that matches any text up to the first 4 consecutive `\r` symbols (or the end of string).

Comment: Glad it worked. If my answer turned out helpful, please also consider upvoting.